# separate List by heads

Tags: haskell

I have problems trying to separate a list follows, suppose we have the following lists

---

```
[[1,2,3,4], [5,6,7,8], [9,10,11,12 ], [13,14,15,16,17]].
```

---

The result should be:

```
[[1,5,9,13] [2,6,10,14] [3,7,11,16] [4,8,12,16]]
```

I'm trying to do it the following way:

```
joinHead (x: xs) = map head (x: xs)
separateLists (x: xs) = xs joinHead x ++ separateLists
```

obviously this does not work. I hope you can help me. thx.

Comment: Have you looked at [`Data.List.transpose`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.2/docs/Data-List.html#v:transpose)?  You can view the source from the documentation and see how it's implemented there.  Try converting it from list comprehensions to use `map` instead.

Comment: Indeed, even writing down the signature [would have been enough](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=[[a]]+-%3E+[[a]]) to find the standard implementation of this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I adapted the functions you wrote, `joinHead` and `separateLists`, to make the code work, while preserving the logic you were following. From what I could infer looking at these functions, the idea was to use `joinHead` to extract the first element of each child list and return a new list. Then, this new list should be inserted in the front of a list of lists returned from calling `separateLists` recursively.

Here is the new definition of `joinHead`:

```
joinHead :: [[a]] -> [a]
joinHead ([]:_) = []
joinHead xs     = map head xs
```

Note that the first line checks, through pattern matching, whether the first list contained in the list of lists is empty and, if so, returns an empty list (`[]`). The reasons for that are two:

1. The function `head` is unsafe. That means that calling `head` on an empty list will cause an exception to be thrown (try running in GHCi `head []`);
2. For simplicity, I'm assuming that all the lists were already checked to have the same length (`length (xs !! 0) == length (xs !! 1) ...`).

The definition of `separateLists` is as follows:

```
separateLists :: [[a]] -> [[a]]
separateLists ([]:_)   = []
separateLists ([x]:xs) = [joinHead ([x]:xs)]
separateLists xs       = joinHead xs : separateLists (map tail xs)
```

Again, the first two definitions are necessary for both stopping the recursion and safety purposes. The first line says: "if the first list is empty, then all the elements of all lists were already consumed, so return `[]`". The second line says: "if the first line has exactly one element, then just call `joinHead` and return the result wrapped in a list". Note that in the third definition we have a call to `tail` which, like `head`, throws exceptions when called on `[]`. That's the reason of why we need a separate case for lists of length 1. Finally, the third line, which is executed for lists of length greater than 1, gets a list from `joinHead xs` and insert it (using the "cons" operator `(:)`) in the beginning of the list returned from recursively calling `separateLists`. In this call, we have to take out the first elements of all the lists, that's why we use `map tail xs`.

Now, running:

```
λ: let list = [[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[9,10,11,12],[13,14,15,16,17]]
λ: separateLists list
[[1,5,9,13],[2,6,10,14],[3,7,11,15],[4,8,12,16]]
```

will give you the expected results. I hope it was clear enough. As a final note, I want to point out that this implementation is far from being optimal and, as suggested in the comments, you should probably use the standard `Data.List.transpose`. As an exercise and didatic example, it's fine! ;-)

Comment: Thanks a lot, now I understand how works correctly, it's a bit complex when you are new in this language.

Again thank you for the help :)